# How Serialize a chain JSon with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a question, how I can serialize this string in VB.NEt?
it looks simple but I cannot to do it, the string is

> {
>   "RedeemItems":[{"RedeemCode":"xxxxx"},{"RedeemCode":"xxxxxxxx"},{"AssetKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
>   }

My code is :

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
   Try

  Dim a As New RedItems
  a.RedeemItems.Add(New RedeemCodes With {.RedeemCode = "11"})
  a.RedeemItems.Add(New RedeemCodes With {.RedeemCode = "22"})

  result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a)

 End Sub

Public Class RedItems
Public Property RedeemItems As List(Of RedeemCodes) = New List(Of RedeemCodes)()
End Class

Public Class RedeemCodes
 Public Property RedeemCode() As String
End Class
```

but I know how add the label :"AssetKey",  if I put the label  within  in the class "RedeemCodes" the chain for JSon not work, coul help me please. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to DESerialize that string - it already looks like serialized data. `AssetKey` is another string property on `RedeemItem`.  Your classes are actually messed up: `RedeemCodes` should be `RedeemItem` and you dont add some parts and deserialzie others, you deserialize the whole thing

Comment: Thanks Plutonix...  but if I need serialize this chain.

Comment: What *chain*?  the top text block is already serialized data.  are you trying to read it or create something just like it?  Your question is quite unclear

Comment: I have tried as you say this is my class:

    Public Class RedeemItem
        Public Property RedeemCode() As String
        Public Property AssetKey As String
    End Class


    Public Class Response
        Public Property RedeemItems As New List(Of RedeemItem)
    End Class

but the result is: 

"{"RedeemItems":[{"RedeemCode":"xxxxx","AssetKey":null},{"RedeemCode":"xxxxxxxx","AssetKey":null},{"RedeemCode":null,"AssetKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]}"